# key=value file. Translation tool as Android studio for strings.xml

Tags: android-studio, plugins, internationalization, translation

I would like to know if is any tool available to make easier working with a file like this:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

For translating i18n.properties to different locales, example:

- i18n_en.properties: for English
- i18n_it.properties: for Italian.
- i18n_es.properties: for Spanish
- i18n.properties: for default

I mean, as Android Studio has XML string translation editor.

I'm looking for one of those:

- Online tool to do the translations
- Plugin for Atom/Webstorm
- Custom IDE that is just for translations.

If you know any thing that may help let me know please, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!